# Firebase Database Rules - How to emulate if a key within a tree exists, such as hasOwnProperty

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm delving into Firebase Security rules for my Firebase realtime database, and I've got a tree that's designed like this:

the endpoint: `/projects/${projectId}`

```
{
  "name" : "A Fun Project",
  "users" : {
    "zjy846p8q1TgdTLxjdFr9DVvxa53" : {
      "role" : "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way I could utilize my rules to do something like this?

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "projects": {
      "$projectId": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('users').child(auth.uid).key === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `.hasChild(auth.id)`

Here are my updated rules:

```
{
  "rules": {    
    "projects": {
      "$projectId": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```